# C# currentcultureinfo is different than defined

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I have a problem where my CurrentCulture is is-IS while I dont have that configured not in my web.config, not on my windows xp, and for some reason this is the locale that is taken into my applications...

where can it be?

Comment: May be someone in code sets culture of assembly like that, do you had a look for it ?

Comment: And what language is set first in your Browser?

Comment: it doesnt happen on other computers... only on one

Comment: On that 1 computer, in FireFox, go Tools|Opions|Content and [Languages]. The top language counts.

Answer (score 0):

It could be in the project (.csproj) file.  In VS, unload the project and then edit the project file.

There could be a an XML element named this:

```
<UICulture>en-US</UICulture>
```

This sets the default culture.

Other places it could be are configuration files, it could be set in code somewhere when the application starts, or it could be set in the host HTML page if this is a web application.

Comment: its a website, i dont have CSPROJ

Comment: OK, sorry misunderstood your question, if it is only happening on 1 machine it must be a browser configuration.  I though you were in a development environment and launching it from there.